# APCUPSD and Hyper V R2

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, ups

I'm about to deploy a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with the Hyper V role. I'd like to get away from having to use a network management card with my APC UPS as I'm only shutting down 1 server (it just seems like an unneeded point of failure). I'd like to look into using apcupsd instead.

1. Will this work properly if I use a serial connection?
2. Have you got it working yourself?
3. How is the SNMP monitoring? I really like being able to easily monitor my UPS with SNMP when powerchute is installed. Will I be sacrificing this completely?
4. Is the network management card really the way to go with this? If so, why?

Bonus question: Is there a better UPS out there that I should be recommending in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no responses on this. So I just tested it out myself. Here's my results:

1. This will work properly. You must use a serial connection. USB is not going to work.
2. Yes I got it working and am now using it for a couple of installs with no problems. I also tested it out in a lab and shutdown worked perfectly
3. No SNMP monitoring. This is rather unfortunate. The only way to use any SNMP monitoring software like Nagios is to have a network management card installed or use the PowerChute
4. I really don't see a whole lot of reasons to use a network management card if you're only working with one server. I could be missing something though.

Another note: Make sure you set Hyper V to shutdown DCs on shutdown instead of suspend them. Otherwise, your clocks are messed up for a few minutes following a power restore. Machines other than DCs should not have this problem as they should be syncing their time from the Hyper V server.

Comment: +1, Also I know you only have 1 host; but if you have DCs on another computer ever, and you suspend/save a VM DC, it can cause major problems in AD replication and you can end up with mild corruption.

Comment: I'm not so sure suspending a DC can cause corruption in most instances. Microsoft only seems to mention corruption caused by pausing it for longer than the tombstone period (90 or 180 days). http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888794 I've seen other mentions elsewhere that say you shouldn't pause but never seen a reason why. Hmmmmm...maybe it's a good ServerFault question - http://serverfault.com/questions/157994/why-shouldnt-a-domain-controller-be-suspended-or-paused